# How to fix join error in mysql update query

Tags: mysql, join, syntax, sql-update

[image]

I had an error in mysql as picture. please help me

sql code is following:

```
UPDATE
  tbl_users AS Users
SET
  Users.money_current = Users.money_current +
  CASE
    WHEN TempTbl.money_info IS NULL
    THEN 0
    ELSE TempTbl.money_info
  END
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
      userId,
      SUM(bet_money * bet_rate) AS money_info
    FROM
      tbl_betting
    WHERE ROUND = 'xxx'
      AND is_win = 1
    GROUP BY userId) AS TempTbl
    ON Users.userId = TempTbl.userId
   FROM tbl_users AS Users;
```

Comment: `JOIN` has to be before `SET`.

Comment: See Multiple-table syntax: here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Comment: Please post your code as text, not images.

Comment: UPDATE
  tbl_users AS Users
SET
  Users.money_current = Users.money_current +
  CASE
    WHEN TempTbl.money_info IS NULL
    THEN 0
    ELSE TempTbl.money_info
  END
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
      userId,
      SUM(bet_money * bet_rate) AS money_info
    FROM
      tbl_betting
    WHERE ROUND = '965802'
      AND is_win = 1
    GROUP BY userId) AS TempTbl
    ON Users.userId = TempTbl.userId
   FROM tbl_users AS Users;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
UPDATE tbl_users AS Users 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT userId, SUM(bet_money * bet_rate) AS money_info 
  FROM tbl_betting WHERE ROUND = '965802' AND is_win = 1 
  GROUP BY userId
) AS TempTbl ON Users.userId = TempTbl.userId
SET Users.money_current = Users.money_current + COALESCE(TempTbl.money_info, 0)
```

I also changed that `CASE` expression with `COALESCE()`.
But I think an `INNER JOIN` would also work in your case, since the unmatched rows of the `LEFT JOIN` that you use do not change the value of `money_current`.

Comment: excellent. you are an expert in mysql query. thanks to appreciate.